# Left and Right Banner image not showing in IE7 and IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I really need some help here regarding two banners for the website that I am currently making.

and I'm currently making a CSS hack for IE8 and IE7.

The problem is that, in IE7 and 8, the image banners are out of place, but works in all other browser and IE9 - 10.

My CSS code for the banners:

```
#leftBanner {
background:url('../../images/Index/BGleftside.jpg') no-repeat;
width: 183px;
height: 1100px;
float: left;
```

}

```
#bodyWrapper {
width:980px;
float: left;
```

}

```
#rightBanner {
background:url('../images/Index/BGrightside.jpg') no-repeat;
width: 183px;
height: 1100px;
float: right;
```

}

and the HTML code: (i removed the js script so that it'll be shorter)

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="mainHeader"> // mainHeader content </div>
    <div class="mainNavBar"> // mainNavBar content </div>
    <div id="leftBanner"> just an empty DIV, contains the image only </div>
    <div id="bodyWrapper"> // bodyWrapper content // </div>
    <div id="rightBanner"> just an empty DIV, contains the image only </div>
</div>
```

In IE8, the leftbanner is missing, and the rightbanner is at the bottom of the page, exactly after the footer div,
and in IE7, both images are missing. :(

i tried from  `position:relative;`  to  `position:absolute;` , still no luck. :(

Comment: Try adding `width:1346px` to body.

Comment: did it, but still no change.. im currently making a css hack for IE8 and IE7 since it was recommended by my senior,

Comment: It is working good i think you are missing image path.

Comment: ok, i tried editing it and the leftbanner appeared, i added the ../ hack needed for the backgroundimage,  background:url('../../images/Index/BGleftside.jpg') no-repeat; , i need to make the rightbanner go up since it is still below the footer div,. :(

Comment: the leftbanner appeared where I want it, my only problem is that the rightbanner is still below the footer DIV, if i remove the float:right it disappears, if i add the position: absolute it overlaps the leftbanner side, :(